# Vue does not see the component from my plugin

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My plugin; currently contains just one component (implemented in TypeScript):

```js
import _Vue, { PluginObject } from "Vue";
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent.vue";

const VuePlugin: PluginObject<void> = {
  install(Vue: typeof _Vue): void {
    Vue.component(MyComponent.name, MyComponent);
    console.log("---");
  }
};

export default VuePlugin;
```

I expect that `MyComponent` will be visible globally thanks to `Vue.component(MyComponent.name, MyComponent);`.

Usage:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import MyPlugin from "my-plugin/VuePlugin";
import RootComponent from "@SourceFiles:StaticView/RootComponent.vue";


(function executeApplication(): void {

  Vue.use(MyPlugin);

  new Vue({
    el: "#Application",
    template: "<RootComponent />",
    components: { RootComponent }
  });
})();
```

```
<template lang="pug">
  MyComponent 
    div OK
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";

  @Component
  export default class RootComponent extends Vue {}
</script>
```

The code until `console.log("---");` (from plugin code) executed without errors.
However, than Vue error occurred:

```
Unknown custom element: <DevelopmentBuildAnywherePageVue> - did you register
 the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

What I missed?

Comment: where did you declare this DevelopmentBuildAnywherePageVue?

Comment: What is `MyComponent.name`?

Comment: @nada Oh, it's the `VuePlugin.ts` from the second listing. It was enough for solving that you payed my attention to this. Thank you for the comment!

Answer (score -1):

This is wrong component name mistake. `DevelopmentBuildAnywherePageVue` is the  `VuePlugin`, the file name from the second listing, but the component name is `MyComponent`. The mistake is in real project file name `DevelopmentBuildAnywherePageVue` was in the template instead of the component name `MyComponent`.

Thanks to @nada for paying my attention.